# how to configure salt-ssh's roster?

Tags: salt-stack

How to configure salt-ssh's roster file [/etc/salt/roster] with common parameter 'user' for all nodes?

I've already searched it on below docs but couldn't find it.
  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/ssh/index.html#salt-ssh-roster
  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/ssh/roster.html

here is what I have now:

```
host1-dev:
    host: host1-dev.mydomain.com
    user: myUser
host2-dev:
    host: host2-dev.mydomain.com
    user: myUser
host1-qa:
    host: host1-qa.mydomain.com
    user: myUser
```

Looking to simplify it like something below:

```
common:
    user: myUser
host1-dev:
    host: host1-dev.mydomain.com
host2-dev:
    host: host2-dev.mydomain.com
host1-qa:
    host: host1-qa.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Jinja to the rescue, although you can't achieve exactly what you want, but you can save yourself some typing with something like this:

```
{% set hosts = ['host1-dev.mydomain.com', 'host2-dev.mydomain.com', 'host1-qa.mydomain.com'] %}
{% set user = 'some_user' %}
{% set pass = 'some_pass' %}

{% for host in hosts %}
{{ host.split('.')[0] }}:
  host: {{ host }}
  user: {{ user }}
  passwd: {{ pass }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the jinja code snippet & trying to answer, +1. This may probably increase the complexity rather reduce. What I mean is, I can have a line `user: myUser` for each host instead bringing in jinja file.